# How to pass parameter to selector in swift?

Tags: swift, selector, addobserver

```
func addObserver(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
  NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(XXX), name:, object:)
}

@objc func getScrollView (_ notification: Notification, useScrollView : UIScrollView) {
 // Doing something for scrollView
 
}
```

I want to pass the scrollView to the objc function getScrollView when I call addObserver function. How should I modify those two functions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is simpler to use block, like

```
private var _observer: Any!  // unsubscribed automatically on deinit

func addObserver(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    _observer = NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(forName: name, 
                object: nil, queue: nil) { notification in
        // ... just use scrollView here
    }
}
```